# Merging/dissolving line features that only touch one other line using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, intersection

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a line feature class that contains a stream network. Some of the line features have vertices where they are only connected to/ touching one other line (i.e. not where two streams come together/ nodes). How do I make these "multi-part lines" into one line feature?

In my image, I have the stream network with points delineating vertices along the line. I am looking to eliminate the vertices (inside the red circle) and combine the multiple parts into one line segment (green rectangle) while still maintaining points of convergence/ nodes for where 2 or more line features intersect.

[image]

Comment: Not sure it has any exact answers to your question, but you might get some ideas from this ArcPro page on network connectivity https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/understanding-connectivity.htm